# Displaying data from an array in a HTML table using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to display data from an array in a table as follows:

```
Download    Upload    BT            TTB
10          5         Available     Available
9           3         Available     Not Available
```

the array looks like:

```
[products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => 20CN ADSL Max
                [likely_down_speed] => 1
                [likely_up_speed] => 0.1
                [availability] => 1
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 0.75 to 2.5
                [provider] => WBC_20CN
                [technology] => ADSL
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => 21CN ADSL 2+
                [likely_down_speed] => 1
                [likely_up_speed] => 0.05
                [availability] => 1
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 1 to 3.5
                [provider] => WBC_21CN
                [technology] => ADSL2+
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => 21CN Annex M
                [likely_down_speed] => 1
                [likely_up_speed] => 0.5
                [availability] => 1
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 1 to 3.5
                [provider] => WBC_21CN
                [technology] => AnnexM
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Fibre to the Cabinet (FTTC)
                [likely_down_speed] => 
                [likely_up_speed] => 
                [availability] => 
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 
                [provider] => WBC_21CN
                [technology] => FTTC
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Fibre to the Premises (FTTP)
                [likely_down_speed] => 
                [likely_up_speed] => 
                [availability] => 
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 
                [provider] => WBC_21CN
                [technology] => FTTP
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => FTTP on Demand
                [likely_down_speed] => 330
                [likely_up_speed] => 30
                [availability] => 1
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 
                [provider] => WBC_21CN
                [technology] => FTTPoD
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [6] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => G.Fast
                [likely_down_speed] => 
                [likely_up_speed] => 
                [availability] => 
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 
                [provider] => WBC_21CN
                [technology] => G.Fast
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [7] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => TalkTalk LLU ADSL 2+
                [likely_down_speed] => 0.89
                [likely_up_speed] => 
                [availability] => 1
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 0.06 to 1.73
                [provider] => TTB
                [technology] => LLU
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [8] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => TalkTalk LLU Annex M
                [likely_down_speed] => 0.39
                [likely_up_speed] => 0.5
                [availability] => 1
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 1.13 to 2.62
                [provider] => TTB
                [technology] => AnnexM
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

        [9] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => TalkTalk FTTC
                [likely_down_speed] => 
                [likely_up_speed] => 
                [availability] => 
                [availability_date] => 
                [speed_range] => 
                [provider] => TTB
                [technology] => FTTC
                [limited_capacity] => 
            )

    )
```

I cannot change the format of the array since its being returned from an API.

The end columns BT and TTB are based on the `provider` key from the array.

Because they are displaying as products, I cannot work out how to display them in the table as above.

I thought about doing something like this:

```
foreach($availability->products as $res) {
    if($res->provider == 'TTB') {
        $ttb[] = $res;
    } else {
        $bt[] = $res;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using object member syntax (`->`) where it appears you should be using array syntax; e.g: `$availability['products']`. In each iteration `$res` is an object so using `->` should be appropriate there.

Comment: the array is returned in objects, im using a `print_r` to output the data for testing

Comment: Okay, just to clarify - If the output of `print_r($availability)` is what you are showing in your answer above - it appears that `$availability` is an associative array, with key `products`. The value of `products` is an array of `stdClass()` objects. Since it's an array, you need to use the array dereference syntax, which is `$availability['products']`, not `$availability->products`. The arrow syntax (`->`) is for objects only.

Comment: @DarraghEnright yes it is, and yes i see what you mean now. What about displaying in the table format I put?

Comment: Where do the 'Download' and 'Upload' values come from - `likely_down_speed` and `likely_up_speed` respectively?

Comment: yes, thats right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181907/discussion-between-darragh-enright-and-charlie).

Comment: In the first row in your example you show BT = Available, TTB = Available, but the code you showed suggests that only one or the other should be available. Can you explain the logic there a bit more?

Comment: @Don'tPanic depending on the results, both or just one could be available

Comment: I see. How does it relate to the provider key, then? It looks like that only holds one value per record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions, show code, and then explain:

- `provider` being `TTB` means that `TTB` is available, and the `BT` is not, and inverse.
- the data structure is an object with a key called products which is an array of many objects
- The download/upload is from the fields that begin with `likely_`
- when you say table output, I'm assuming you mean HTML table

With that in mind, check out this code:

```
$result = new stdClass;
$result->products = [
  (object) [
    'name' => '20CN ADSL Max',
    'likely_down_speed' => 1,
    'likely_up_speed' => 0.1,
    'availability' => 1,
    'availability_date' => null,
    'speed_range' => '0.75 to 2.5',
    'provider' => 'WBC_20CN',
    'technology' => 'ADSL',
    'limited_capacity' => null
  ],

  (object) [
    'name' => 'TalkTalk FTTC',
    'likely_down_speed' => null,
    'likely_up_speed' => null,
    'availability' => null,
    'availability_date' => null,
    'speed_range' => null,
    'provider' => 'TBB',
    'technology' => 'FTTC',
    'limited_capacity' => null
  ],
];

echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Download</th><th>Upload</th><th>BT</th><th>TBB</th>";
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($result->products as $product) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . (int) $product->likely_down_speed . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . (int) $product->likely_up_speed . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . ($product->provider === 'TTB' ? "Not Available" : "Available") . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . ($product->provider !== 'TTB' ? "Available" : "Not Available") . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Here's what's going on.

The first variable `$result` is what I think your data structure looks like.  When there are blank outputs, I made them null.

Then, we create a table with the `echo` statements to give the headers that you wanted.

Next, loop through the products.  For each product make a row.

Output the first down/up as integers.  *Note that this will make null values output as zeros. You may want to change this.*

Next, based on our provider, we'll either print available or not available.  So, if the provider is TTB, that means we'll print that BT is not available, and TTB is.

The end closes up this table.

Answer (score 0):

in your html (view) file

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
 <td>Download</td>
 <td>Upload</td>
 <td>BT</td>
 <td>TTB</td>
</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>
<?php
  foreach($availability["products"] as $res)
 {
  ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php  echo $res->likely_down_speed;  ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $res->likely_up_speed;  ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $res->provider !="TTB"?"Available":"Not Available";  ?></td>
     <td><?php  echo $res->provider =="TTB"?"Available":"Not Available";  ?></td>
   </tr>
  <?php
 }


?>


</tbody>



</table>
```

where $res is represent each stdClass Object in $availability["products"] array

Answer (score 0):

this is simple first parent array
    **$availability['products'];**
like:

```
array( // this line is first parent array
array('key' => 'value','key' => 'value'), // this line is objects
array('key' => 'value','key' => 'value'), // this line is objects
array('key' => 'value','key' => 'value'), // this line is objects
array('key' => 'value','key' => 'value'), // this line is objects
);


foreach($availability['products'] as $res) {
        if($res->provider == 'TTB') {
            $ttb[] = $res;
        } else {
            $bt[] = $res;
        }
    }
```

your output:

```
 print_r($ttb);
    print_r($bt);
```